# Translate Erpnext workspace to different languages

Tags: translation, google-translate, erpnext, frappe

Hello I have faced problem whenever I change language for workspace in erpnext it never fully translates everything. Any Advice how to make translations easy, fast and simple [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCpmd.png)

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation.
https://frappeframework.com/docs/v13/user/en/guides/basics/contribute_translations

May be this documentation solve your problem.